# I am trying to echo a button that pulls content in a file but it outputs outside of the HTML tag

Tags: php, include, echo, require

I am trying to echo a button that pulls content from a file that has variable set on it.

```
        $vidplayBtn = require __DIR__ . '\..\vid-play-btn.php';
        if( $displayButton ) { 
            $output = '<div class="hero-video-play"><div class="container">';
            $output .= $vidplayBtn;
            $output .= '</div></div>'; 

            echo $output;
        }
```

But the result outputs the button outside the containing HTML tag and adds a 1 character inside it.

```
<a href="#jsModalVideo" rel="modal:open" role="button" class="btn_play btn_play_color-" title=""> <div class="flex__container_btn-play"> <p>What makes us different?</p> <svg .... </svg> </div> </a>

<div class="hero-video-play"><div class="container">1</div></div>
```

Below is the content of vid-play-btn.php.

```
<a href="#jsModalVideo<?= $btn_play_c_video_id ?>" rel="modal:open" role="button" class="btn_play btn_play_color-<?= $btn_play_c_color ?>" title="<?= $btn_play_c_title ?>">
  <div class="flex__container_btn-play">
        <p><?= $btn_play_c_caption ?></p>
        <svg version="1.1" class="play" x="0px" y="0px" height="100px" width="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve"> <path class="stroke-solid" fill="none" stroke="white" d="M49.9,2.5C23.6,2.8,2.1,24.4,2.5,50.4C2.9,76.5,24.7,98,50.3,97.5c26.4-0.6,47.4-21.8,47.2-47.7 C97.3,23.7,75.7,2.3,49.9,2.5"/> <path class="stroke-dotted" fill="none" stroke="white" d="M49.9,2.5C23.6,2.8,2.1,24.4,2.5,50.4C2.9,76.5,24.7,98,50.3,97.5c26.4-0.6,47.4-21.8,47.2-47.7 C97.3,23.7,75.7,2.3,49.9,2.5"/> <path class="icon" fill="white" d="M38,69c-1,0.5-1.8,0-1.8-1.1 V32.1c0-1.1,0.8-1.6,1.8-1.1l34,18c1,0.5,1,1.4,0,1.9 L38,69z"/> </svg>
  </div></a>
```

What could be causing it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `vid-play-btn.php` return the `<a...>` or does it `echo` it? If it echoes it, then that will happen when you require it, it won't save the output in `$vidplayBtn`.

Comment: You can use the output buffering functions to capture the output.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to fix it with the above suggestion.